# How to check a list for a string then select the rest of that item,

Tags: python, list

At the moment I have a text file with people who swim and their times, such as this,

```
jack 12
sarah 20
ben 4
```

Now i would like to be able to search this for say sarah and for it to return the code.

This is what i currently have.

```
def Timers(swimmer):
  myFile = open("race.txt","r")
  lists = []
  for eachLine in myFile:
      lists += [eachLine.rstrip("\n")]
```

so I compiled all them into a single list, although i know i can check the list to see if they are there although i cannot work out how i would just select the time.

At this point i know if i get say, `sarah 12` I can then use split and then just formate it to get the times.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach to the problem:

```
def Timer(swimmer):
    myFile = open("race.txt", "r")
    lists = myFile.readlines()
    found = [l for l in lists if l.startswith(swimmer)][0]  # Gets first found swimmer
    time = found.split()[-1]  # Gets last item (eg. time) in splitted list
    myFile.close()
    return time

print Timer('jack')
```

This works even if the swimmer is specified with both first and last name. I used the same way to open the file as you did. But you really should use the with-statement as in the previous answer!

Comment: Please may you explade or point me where i can learn more about this line,[l for l in lists if l.startswith(swimmer)][0]? Thank you

Comment: For anyone looking at this, the found line is saying "[(do this for every element) for element in (list or iterable) if (this condition applies)]" credit to jakebird451

Comment: Good morning ;) Yeah, it's called a list comprehension.

I'm not sure my solution really is better than Martijns (I thought it was clever to use a dict). The thing my solution solves where his fails are if the name includes a whitespace. There are double names that do and maybe you would like to separate to ppl with the same first name by using a sir name. The "magic" I'm using is `found.split()[-1]` which selects the LAST "column" instead of the SECOND one. You could easily rewrite Martijns function to do this as well.

Answer (score 2):

You want a `dict`, a python mapping instead, and read the file only *once*:

```
def Timers():
    with open("race.txt","r") as myFile:
        swimmers = {}
        for eachLine in myFile:
            if line.strip():
                swimmer, timer = line.split()
                swimmers[swimmer] = timer
    return swimmers
```

The `.split()` call splits the line on whitespace, giving you a name and a timer string for each line.

Now `Timers()` returns a mapping containing all swimmer names as the keys, and their times as values. You can simply look up each and every swimmer:

```
timers = Timers()
print timers['sarah']
```

Comment: Thanks man i was about to reply and i got a bluescreen, let me test some of this out.

Comment: Do work as long as no one has a double name or something... Though it was a good idea to just return a dictionary which, as you know but maybe not to OP, will make it alot faster if there are many look ups :)